# How to use special key combinations in flash/actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, browser, actionscript, keyboard

Hi I am building a rich web application using Flash / ActionScript 3 which needs to use special key combinations inside (like Ctrl+R, F5 etc). But browser looks like always have a priority in processing these combinations. I found a line in Adobe documentation which said that "Browser has a priority in keyboard".

Do you know a way to override this?

Answer (score 0):

You could listen to key events inside your actionscript or javascript code and call [Event.preventDefault()](http://help.adobe.com/ru_RU/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#preventDefault()) to disable some (not all) browser bindings.